# Pandas: Find index of max string value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have some time values that are in string format. I would like to return the value of the most recent or "max" time in a column. I noticed that argmax and idmax don't work for strings. I would like to avoid converting them to find the index of the max value. Is there a way to return the index of the max string value?

```
df['Start_time'].max()
```

returns:
'2017-05-02 15:47:21'

```
df.loc[df['Start_time'].idxmax()]
```

returns:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2017-01-26 16:33:16'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If dont want converting to `datetime`, you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with comparing column with `max` value:

```
print (df[df['Start_time'] == df['Start_time'].max()])
```

And for index is possible use:

```
df.index[df['Start_time'] == df['Start_time'].max()][0]
```

Or:

```
df[df['Start_time'] == df['Start_time'].max()].index[0]
```

Comment: Thanks that works. This returns the index value only: df[df['Start_time'] == df['Start_time'].max()].index[0]

Comment: @sparrow - yes, exactly. I add it to answer with similar solution.

Answer (score 4):

Source DF:

```
In [60]: df
Out[60]:
            Start_time
0  2017-05-01 16:16:16
1  2017-05-02 15:47:21
2  2017-05-01 10:10:10
```

Solution 1:

```
In [61]: df.iloc[df['Start_time'].values.argmax()]
Out[61]:
Start_time    2017-05-02 15:47:21
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Solution 2:

```
In [62]: df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['Start_time']).idxmax()]
Out[62]:
Start_time    2017-05-02 15:47:21
```